# Excel 2007 Find number of days, based on current date, only if < or > then 2 different dates of same year & month

Tags: excel-2007

I have a question for Excel2000 want to do a simple calculation.

I need only one formula if possible include question in the formula to solve it.

Question Condition:

Date 01/Aug/2013 till 31/Aug/2013 in format 08/01/2013 till 08/31/2013 & the current date is 25/08/2013.

Question: Repeated several time for better understanding.

Excel should only do days calculation, based on current date only if the current date is within two date, from 08/01/2013 not less than or greater than 08/31/2013 if <> should remain blank, if within the period to find number of days, for the current month Aug of the year 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a setup like this:

```
   _____A____  _____B____  ______C_____  _______D______
1  Start Date  End Date    Today's Date  Days Remaining
2  08/01/2013  08/31/2013    08/25/2013               6
```

This formula in cell D2 should work:

```
=IF(OR(C2<A2,C2>B2),"",B2-C2)
```